# Search for a term in specific parts of the world

Tags: search

I'm trying to find specific (science-related) items in Google or any other search engine. I'd like to limit answers to those from Europe, Asia (but without China) and South America; specifically I'd like to exclude USA and China (I'm getting lots of unrelated answers from pages there).

The pages I expect to get are always in English, so I cannot filter by language.

I guess I could filter by domain, but I'd like to limit number of queries.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you select "Advanced Search" in Google, then expand the "Date, usage rights, numeric range, and more" section, there is a "Region" dropdown. It only appears to list countries, and you can probably only search one country at a time, but this could be helpful. Not sure how accurate the Region filter is though.